# How To Validate TextBox after Pressing TAB Key in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to make validation whether user has entered something or not in textbox as soon as he presses the TAB key. if the textbox is blank and he presses the TAB key it will say "please enter" else call something...

Comment: There are several ways to validate controls in WPF, but I like the INotifyDataErrorInfo method. Then you can display errors either as the user types or when they leave the control (by pressing tab). You were probably downvoted because this is a common question, and there are lots of post on how to do this.

Comment: clould you please share links or example for that?, I tired to search in google but i have not seen any solution

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/876349/wpf-validation-using-inotifydataerrorinfo https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/inotifydataerrorinfo-in-wpf/

Comment: In short, your models should all share a base class that implements the interface. The models check their properties when they change so they know if they are valid and what any errors are. The XAML looks for objects that implement the interface and automatically displays the Error template for the bound control. By default it's a red border.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write validation for length and empty checks on lost_focus event of textbox (or) to write same validation preview key down (check for e.Key==Key.Tab)